# can someone guide me on the use case for serving media files via uploadcare vs amazon S3 vs other solutions?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, uploadcare

I am trying to make a django application (with the Rest framework) and I was just researching and came across different ways to serve media files.

what is the recommended approach for a project/app that lets you upload pictures so that other users can download them?

I came across CDN such as uploadcare, cloudinary and then ofcourse amazon S3 as well. Is there a difference in using these services like uploadcare vs S3 in terms of speed or scaling?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi Karan, this is Alex from Uploadcare. AWS S3 is just object storage. If you need CDN delivery for your project, you can add Cloudfront and get it to serve your files stored in S3. Such services as Cloudinary or Uploadcare provides file storage + CDN delivery + URL-based image/video transformations out of the box. Our platform is not only file storage but a full-fledged file backend that you can easily integrate into your project using our Python/Django API client (https://github.com/uploadcare/pyuploadcare)

Comment: so I'm guessing if your app doesn't need any image/video transformations, then AWS S3 and Cloudfront is the way to go right?